# How to allow connections only from frontend container to backend container?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, server, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup my frontend, backend and my DB using docker. Here are the conditions where only my frontend container should make request to backend and not to the public. I have written a conf file but that still I'm able to access the backend with postman. Also I'm moving the frontend build files to a volume and mounting it in `/usr/share/nginx/html` where then the frontend container will stop and files will be served directly from nginx container.

Is it good to have another nginx service running in frontend container where the main nginx container route to frontend nginx service?

default.conf

```
upstream backend_servers {
    server backend:8000;
}


server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/frontend;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # Reverse proxy requests to the uWSGI server
    location /api {
        rewrite ^/api(.*) $1 break;
        uwsgi_pass backend_servers;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

my Docker compose file is

```
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    volumes:
      - app-data:/app/dist

  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    environment:
      - DEBUG=0
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS=nginx,localhost,127.0.0.1
      - SECRET_KEY=my-secure-key
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  nginx:
    build: 
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - app-data:/usr/share/nginx/html/frontend
    depends_on:
      - backend

volumes:
  db-data:
  app-data:
```

Comment: Since you don't map the port from your backend container to a host port, it's only containers on the docker network that can (easily) call the backend container. That's not good enough? If it isn't, can you describe the type of calls to the backend that you want to prevent?

Comment: What sort of application is the frontend?  If you're serving a browser-based application, maybe based on React or Angular, that will not run in a container, and you must allow inbound non-container connections, at which point you can't restrict which clients are able to call.  Chaining Nginxes is fine, it will add a hop of latency but you're unlikely to notice.